# Compiling C++ code with G++ compiler from Android NDK r25

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, g++, clang++

I just recently downloaded `Android NDK version r25` and looking through it shows no `GCC/G++` compiler anymore and all it has is `clang/clang++`.

How can I compile my C++ code still with G++ compiler but for newest versions of Android (like Android 13)?

**Note:** I have no background in clang compiler at all.

Comment: C++ is C++ no matter the compiler. Unless you plan to use compiler-specific and non-standard extensions? But both Clang and GCC are pretty much compatible when it comes to them as well, though there are some differences. You can read the Clang documentation to see if the compiler-specific extensions you want to use are available in Clang. However, if you don't plan to use compiler-specific extensions, and only use standard C++ and the platform-specific functionality for Android, the choice of compiler shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. This is because I had a really hard time to make a huge C++ project on Linux OS and with G++ it works perfectly. Now I am supposed to compile it for another platform (namely Android phone) and I need to move to cross compilation zone and use android NDK toolchains.